# Excel conditional formatting works several times, then stops

Tags: conditional-formatting, excel-365

The spreadsheet has 2 columns in which the cells have formatting dependent on whether the cell value is greater than or less than a number in a cell at the top of the column.  The values in the cells are calculated in VBA code; the reference cell is a hand-entered value, not a formula.

In testing it was found that the format changes as designed the first time either of the 2 references are changed (i.e., the formatting changes when the reference value is changed and Enter is pressed) and then both quit responding to subsequent changes. Sometimes it has worked 2, 3, or 4 times before stopping.

Further testing found that, after the problem manifests, the formatting will update when:

- a column is hidden
- the file is saved
- a value in some (but not all) other cells is changed
- the focus is changed to another application.
- forced recalculate (Ctrl + Alt + F9)

But refresh (Shift-Ctrl-F5) does not cause a format update

There are no formulas embedded in cells.  The conditional formatting is defined in VBA code.

The Sheet VBA code has a Worksheet_Change subroutine that I considered modifying, but conditional formatting as simple as this shouldn't require an external refresh.  And if it did, it wouldn't change behavior after several uses.

I looked for an existing description of this problem before posting this.  Has anyone else experienced this or know what can be done about it?

Excel version is 2304 on Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was caused by inconsistent use of the Application.EnableEvents flag. After comparing the program with a manually-generated clone and scrubbing the code it now works correctly.

I'm not sure why worksheet_change would affect conditional formatting; the cell(s) that determine the conditional state aren't in the target intersection range.  When a change event happened

1. the events are disabled,
2. the range-check performed & failed (because the change was in a cell outside the range),
3. then the events enabled,
4. exit the routine.

That part was done correctly; the problem was in the other subroutines which have the events-disable at the beginning of the section and an enable at the end.  But some had a check with a possible sub-exit that didn't enable events on the way out. After reorganizing those, it works as it should.